# How to indent multiple inline words in Qplaintextedit?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a Qplaintextedit in my program and I want to display columns of data in it. For this reason I want to indent parts of each line.

```
text = QPlainTextEdit(self)
text.appendHtml("<div width = \"100%\"><span style=\"display: inline; left: 20px;position: absolute;\">text1</span><span style=\"display: inline; left: 60px;position: absolute;\">text2</span></div>")
```

or

```
text = QPlainTextEdit(self)
text.appendHtml("<table width = \"100%\"><tr><td>text1</td><td>text2</td></tr></table>")
```

Tried these 2 html/css approaches but they do not work.

I know there is QTextTable, but I couldn't figure out how to move between cells set their properties or how to insert data.

Example of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: What about using a <table>?

Comment: That is actually a good idea, I will try it.

Comment: okay, <table> didn't work out, couldn't set it's width, border etc

Comment: I suggest you to edit your post showing us what you tried.

Comment: fair enough, edited

Comment: Use QTextEdit and change to `text.append('...')`.

Comment: Also remember that Qt has a very basic support for a [subset of HTML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) (and css, with only a partial implementation of CSS 2.1), so the first approach wouldn't work anyway. You must use a <table> for that. QTextTable is for QTextDocument manipulation, but for your needs I doubt you'll need to dig into that (and, in any case, you should study the documentation about [Qt Rich Text Processing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext.html), which is **not** an easy nor short subject).

Comment: QTextEdit and append does exactly what I wanted, thanks